# How can I get elements from 3D matrix using specified indices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

- I have a 3D matrix, in below example it's a (5, 4, 2) matrix: `data_matrix`
- I have a another index array of shape (5, 4) where each row of array represent the element location: `indx_array`

I don't know how can I get the `required_output`. I'm trying to arrange (1,2) elements of each row based on the `indx_array`

**I don't want to use for loops!**

```py
data_matrix = np.array([
    [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]],
    [[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]], 
    [[16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21], [22, 23]], 
    [[24, 25], [26, 27], [28, 29], [30, 31]], 
    [[32, 33], [34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39]]
])

indx_array = np.array([[3,2,1,0], [0,1,2,3], [1,0,3,2], [0,3,1,2], [1,2,3,0]])


# I want following result:
required_output = [
    [[6, 7], [4, 5], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
    [[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]]
    [[18, 19], [16, 17], [22, 23], [20, 21]]
    [[24, 25], [30, 31], [26, 27], [28, 29]]
    [[34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39], [32, 33]]
]
```

EDIT: Updated the `indx_array` to better illustrate the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Numpy: Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing)

  - [Numpy: Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

```py
In [637]: data_matrix.shape                                                                          
Out[637]: (5, 4, 2)
In [638]: indx_array.shape                                                                           
Out[638]: (5, 4)
```

You need advanced-indexing on the first 2 dimensions.  The first dimension array needs to broadcast with the second (5,4).  To do that I make a (5,1) `arange`:

```
In [639]: data_matrix[np.arange(5)[:,None], indx_array]                                              
Out[639]: 
array([[[ 6,  7],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[18, 19],
        [16, 17],
        [22, 23],
        [20, 21]],

       [[24, 25],
        [30, 31],
        [26, 27],
        [28, 29]],

       [[34, 35],
        [36, 37],
        [38, 39],
        [32, 33]]])
```

Contrast my (5,1) index with the accepted `_x` (which is (5,4) ravelled):

```
In [640]: np.arange(5)[:,None]                                                                       
Out[640]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
In [641]: _x = np.repeat(np.arange(indx_array.shape[0]),indx_array.shape[1])                         
In [643]: _x                                                                                         
Out[643]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

With broadcasting the `_x` doesn't need the repeat, (5,4); (5,1) is enough.

Broadcasting does a virtual repetition.  This can be illustrated with the `broadcast_to` function:

```
In [648]: np.broadcast_to(np.arange(5)[:,None],(5,4))                                                
Out[648]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])
In [649]: _.strides                                                                                  
Out[649]: (8, 0)
```

It's that `0` strides that repeats without making copies.  `as_strided` is the most useful `stride_tricks` function, especially when doing things like moving windows.  Usually we just let the automatic broadcasting do the work without worrying too much about the how.

Comment: @hpaulj It's too much to ask and I'm not sure if you have any idea on this, but I'm trying to apply this same logic on Tensors. Since, tensorflow doesn't allow easy indexing, I'm not sure how can I convert this logic. Feel free to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431408/how-can-i-access-elements-of-a-3d-tensor-using-specified-indices-in-tensorflow

Comment: I know tensorflow only by analogy to numpy

Comment: Thanks man, I got it with TF; it's pretty straightforward actually: `tf.gather(data_matrix, indx_array, batch_dims=1).numpy().tolist()`

Answer (score 4):

Can be done with a little bit of handing of the index array.

```py
import numpy as np

_x = np.repeat(np.arange(indx_array.shape[0]),indx_array.shape[1])
_y = indx_array.ravel()

output = data_matrix[_x, _y].reshape(data_matrix.shape)
```

which results in the expected numpy array

```
array([[[ 6,  7],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[18, 19],
        [16, 17],
        [22, 23],
        [20, 21]],

       [[24, 25],
        [30, 31],
        [26, 27],
        [28, 29]],

       [[34, 35],
        [36, 37],
        [38, 39],
        [32, 33]]])
```