# How can I access elements of a 3D tensor using specified indices in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to get the rows of a 3D tensor in a specific order of indices. Here are the inputs:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

matrix = tf.constant([
    [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]], 
    [[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]], 
    [[16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21], [22, 23]], 
    [[24, 25], [26, 27], [28, 29], [30, 31]], 
    [[32, 33], [34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39]]
])

indx = tf.constant([[3,2,1,0], [0,1,2,3], [1,0,3,2], [0,3,1,2], [1,2,3,0]])

# required output tensor:
[[[6, 7], [4, 5], [2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]],
 [[18, 19], [16, 17], [22, 23], [20, 21]],
 [[24, 25], [30, 31], [26, 27], [28, 29]],
 [[34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39], [32, 33]]]
```

I'm struggling with `tf.gather_nd()`. Any suggestion? I can see it's happening here but I'm not sure **how to apply on entire matrix without using `for` loop or `tf.map_fn`**

```py
print(tf.gather_nd(matrix[0], tf.expand_dims(indx, -1)[0]).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.gather_nd(matrix[1], tf.expand_dims(indx, -1)[1]).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.gather_nd(matrix[2], tf.expand_dims(indx, -1)[2]).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.gather_nd(matrix[3], tf.expand_dims(indx, -1)[3]).numpy().tolist())
print(tf.gather_nd(matrix[4], tf.expand_dims(indx, -1)[4]).numpy().tolist())

"""
[[6, 7], [4, 5], [2, 3], [0, 1]]
[[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]]
[[18, 19], [16, 17], [22, 23], [20, 21]]
[[24, 25], [30, 31], [26, 27], [28, 29]]
[[34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39], [32, 33]]
"""
```

EDIT: I asked a similar question with respect to numpy. A clever indexing answer does solves the numpy version, but it's hard to apply it on Tensors. Feel free to take a look at the accepted answer here: [How can I get elements from 3D matrix using specified indices in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430621/how-can-i-get-elements-from-3d-matrix-using-specified-indices-in-numpy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get elements from 3D matrix using specified indices in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430621/how-can-i-get-elements-from-3d-matrix-using-specified-indices-in-numpy)

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, I asked that with numpy, but it's not related as tensors doesn't allow indexing like numpy arrays

Comment: It is always good to close a question by accepting an answer once an answer resolves the asked question. You can also refer to it and mention you need it specifically in tensorflow and not numpy (and possibly remove numpy tag)

Comment: Yes, I'm closing the numpy version since it was answered there w.r.t numpy array and adding a note here regarding that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Duh, that was stupid! There is already a very great function available that works on multi-dimensional array in tensorflow; **`tf.gather()`** Check out the [batch_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather?hl=en) argument for more information.

```py
>> tf.gather(matrix, indx, batch_dims=1).numpy().tolist()
[[[6, 7], [4, 5], [2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]],
 [[18, 19], [16, 17], [22, 23], [20, 21]],
 [[24, 25], [30, 31], [26, 27], [28, 29]],
 [[34, 35], [36, 37], [38, 39], [32, 33]]]
```